# How to avoid write timer resetting in OkHttpClient in retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying upload multiple photos to server. For fast upload, I am compressing photos before upload. So After this, uploading is super fast when I am connected with Wifi. But in mobile data, taking 5 to 6 minutes. So Searched a bit and found the problem. In OkHttpClient I am setting write time out for 60 seconds. This write time is out getting resetted after one byte transfer to server. So its taking more time for more bytes. How to solve it.
This is the site where I learned about Time outs in Okhttp,

```
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-customize-network-timeouts
```

---> I think of using CountDownTimer after making a retrofit call. So if timer is over then I need to show alert as failed or retry.  But I doen't know where to use it.
So anybody give me better solution for this.

```
 OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

                    builder
                    .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
```

Comment: can you add your snippet here?

Comment: @Rajasekaran M added code snippet pls check it

Comment: FYI : when you are using mobile data , may be data uploading will be taking more time. that's why we need increase `connectTimeout` and `writeTimeout`. you will get SocketTimeout exception when your exceeded the time limit connection and write. you can put your api call inside try block and capture exception in catch block.Then compare exception type for if or when and identify the exception type

Comment: Increase your `connectTimeout`, `readTimeout`  and `writeTimeout` time to 10 minutes(if it's okay for you)

Comment: @Rajasekaran M I want to upload data only for few seconds...if the time taking long I want to show alert...So what will be best way for that

Comment: @Rajasekaran M I am setting write time to 10 secs. once reaching 10 secs, I want to show alert....Is this approach is better

Comment: you have to wait for api response and you should not show alert with static time because api may be take long time when network is low

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203499/discussion-between-rajasekaran-m-and-sandhiya).